# How to make python exit on pyodbc on time out error?

Tags: python, pyodbc

How do I make my python script exit when the database throws *time out error*? I only get the message if I ctrl-c to manually quit - I'd like to get python to **stop immediately** on the error..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=OurDSN", autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM our_table limit 100"
for row in cursor.execute(query):
    print row
```

Error message:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):          
 File "./impala_test.py", line 6, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect("OurDSN=Hive", autocommit=True)
 pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Cloudera][HiveODBC] (34) Error from Hive:    EAGAIN (timed out). (34) (SQLDriverConnect)')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyodbc's [query timeout](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#timeout) is disabled by default. Try setting it to a value you want?